Proof of a complex property
My apologize for the previous post. I am new to this forum and noted i did not provide sufficient detail. I am provided with the property that |z|=1. With this, I am to prove the following: $\left|\frac{2z+1}{2z+4}\right|=\frac{1}{2}$
I have attempted this problem in three ways (always knowing which direction is problematic).

Using multiple by conjugate
$\left|\frac{2z+1}{2z+4}\right|=\left|\frac{2\left(x+iy\right)+1}{2\left(x+iy\right)+4}\right|=\left|\frac{\left(2x+1\right)+iy}{\left(2x+4\right)+iy}\right|\times\left|\frac{\left(2x+4\right)-iy}{\left(2x+4\right)-iy}\right|$
problem: after simplification i cannot equate this to $1/2$

Exponential Properties: $z=re^{i\theta}$
$\left|\frac{2z+1}{2z+4}\right|=\left|\frac{2e^{i\theta}+1}{2e^{i\theta}+4}\right|=\left|\frac{2e^{i\theta}+1}{2{(e}^{i\theta}+2)}\right|=\frac{\left|2e^{i\theta}+1\right|}{2\left|{(e}^{i\theta}+2)\right|}$
This approach i could not understand how:$\left|2e^{i\theta}+1\right|^2=\left(2\ cos\ \theta+1\right)^2+\left(2\ sin\ \theta\right)^2$

On this post:$A=\left(2\ cos\ \theta+1\right)+i\left(2\ sin\ \theta\right)$
Is this a property of complex numbers similar to the approach listed in (2).


At first glance the best method to solving this problem is what i struggle with. Thanks all for your help

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please format this question properly to make it readable. Is the fraction $\frac{2z+1}{2z}+4$ or is it $\frac{2z+1}{2z+4}$? As currently written it looks like the first one.

There must exist a $~\theta~$ such that $~z = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta).~$  So, setting A = $$\left[ \left( ~2\cos \theta + 1 ~\right) + i ~\left(2\sin \theta ~\right) ~\right],$$ and B = $$\left[ \left( ~2\cos \theta + 4 ~\right) + i ~\left(2\sin \theta ~\right) ~\right],$$ the problem reduces to showing that $$\frac{|A|}{|B|} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

By the way.  I agree with the comment of @RedFive, and my previous comment represents my guess that you intended $~\dfrac{2z+1}{2z+4}.$

Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions.

@AnneBauval Completely agree.  However, it seems to me that unless the original poster understands that there exists $~\theta~$ such that $~z = e^{i\theta},~$ the original poster is pretty much dead in the water.  This particular situation is tricky, because even if the original poster were to attempt to study the pertinent previous worked examples, solved problems, and supplied theorems, it is (subjectively) plausible that the $~z = e^{i\theta}~$ idea might escape them.

Hint: $|2z+1|=|2\bar z+1|=|z||2\bar z+1|=|2+z|$

Is it $\frac{2z+1}{2z+4},$ or, as you have written it, $\frac{2z+1}{2z}+4?$

@AnneBauval Again, completely agree with your hint, which leads to a more elegant approach than my comment.  However, your hint may be based on a concept that the original poster is unfamiliar with, and the original poster may therefore lack confidence in that approach.  My (simpler but much less elegant) approach may represent an approach that the original poster has more confidence in.

Again, please avoid "no clue" questions: "Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true (you may genuinely have no idea how to approach the problem), it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts." We'd be more able to tailor a hint appropriate to you if you let us know your way of thinking before.

@AnneBauval Again, completely agree.  Now, it seems to me that your hint and/or my hint will give the original poster a better chance to include their thoughts directly in the posted question.

Thoughts? What have you already done on it? Where are you stuck? Please clarify.

$A=\left(2\cos\theta+1\right)+i\left(2\sin\theta\right)$ is not "a property of complex numbers". It is just the introduction of a notation (namely $A$) for $2z+1$.


$\left|\frac{2z+1}{2z+4}\right|$
is not equal to $\left|\frac{\left(2x+1\right)+iy}{\left(2x+4\right)+iy}\right|\times\left|\frac{\left(2x+4\right)-iy}{\left(2x+4\right)-iy}\right|$ (multiple mistakes here) but to the square root of $\frac{\left(2x+1\right)+i(2y)}{\left(2x+4\right)+i(2y)}\frac{\left(2x+1\right)-i(2y)}{\left(2x+4\right)-i(2y)}$. I.e. $$\begin{align}\left|\frac{2z+1}{2z+4}\right|&=\sqrt{\frac{\left(2x+1\right)^2+(2y)^2}{\left(2x+4\right)^2+(2y)^2}}\\&=\sqrt{\frac{4(x^2+y^2)+4x+1}{4(x^2+y^2)+16x+16}}\\&=\sqrt{\frac{5+4x}{20+16x}}=\sqrt\frac14=\frac12.\end{align}$$
$\left|2e^{i\theta}+1\right|^2=\left(2\cos\theta+1\right)^2+\left(2\sin\theta\right)^2$ because $$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$ and $$\forall(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2\quad|a+ib|^2=a^2+b^2.$$ With this approach (very similar to the previous one), $$\begin{align}\left|\frac{2z+1}{2z+4}\right|^2&=\frac{\left(2\cos\theta+1\right)^2+\left(2\sin\theta\right)^2}{\left(2\cos\theta+4\right)^2+\left(2\sin\theta\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{4\left(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta\right)+4\cos\theta+1}{4\left(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta\right)+16\cos\theta+16}\\
&=\frac14.\end{align}$$
$A=\left(2\cos\theta+1\right)+i\left(2\sin\theta\right)$
is not "a property of complex numbers". It is just a notation (namely $A$
) for $2z+1$, introduced in @user2661923's comment. Their approach was indeed the same as your point 2.
My hint $$|2z+1|=|2\bar z+1|=|z||2\bar z+1|=|2z\bar z+z|=|2+z|$$ led to a more syntetic proof:
$$\left|\frac{2z+1}{2z+4}\right|=\frac{|z+2|}{|2z+4|}=\frac12.$$


thank you. With your help i worked through all my mistakes

We have  $$\left|\frac{2z+1}{2z+4}\right|= \left|\frac{2z+4-3}{2z+4}\right|= \left|1-\frac{3}{2z+4}\right|.$$
So, to prove $\left|\frac{2z+1}{2z+4}\right|=\frac{1}{2}$, we must prove that $\frac{3}{2z+4}$ is a circle with center $1$ and radius $\frac12$. We have
$$\frac{3}{2z+4}= \frac{3}2\cdot\frac1{z+2}.$$
The set of points $z$ is the circle with center $0$ and radius $1$. The set $z+2$ is the circle with center $2$ and radius $1$. The mapping $z+2\mapsto \frac1{z+2}$ transforms the circle into another circle. The segment from $\frac13$ to $1$ is its diameter. So it’s a circle with center $\frac23$ and radius $\frac13$.
After multiplying by $\frac32$ it becomes the circle with center $1$ and radius $\frac12$, as we wanted.
